# Network unreachable, but Google is reachable

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ping

So I have this problem on both my Ubuntu 18.04. (On Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th Gen) and my Ipod Touch 7. On both systems I can connected to my Speedlink 5501 Router via Wifi, but apparently only Google works. If I enter e.g. askubuntu.com, I do not get a connection. All other devices in the network work fine.

I am getting this strange behaviour:

```
max@max-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
max@max-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com(fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:81a::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:81a::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=11.8 ms
64 bytes from fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:81a::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=14.1 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.817/12.974/14.131/1.157 ms
max@max-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th:~$ ping askubuntu.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I cannot even ping my router at 192.168.100.1, nor access the webinterface.

I first thought that it could be a DNS problem, but changing DNS (i.e. adding additional IPs) won't help. How could I resolve the problem? I think, given that many devices in my network work but both the Thinkpad and the Ipod do not work, this is somewhat strange.

The following output might be useful:

```
max@max-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th:~$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f8:75:a4:08:16:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4810  bytes 5092583 (5.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3726  bytes 420311 (420.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xea200000-ea220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2341  bytes 210190 (210.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2341  bytes 210190 (210.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9418:a3d9:4ff1:e94c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fde2:8acd:e9d3:0:429a:b26:8370:18ce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2003:ec:3730:f00:c26b:1148:c6c6:b07c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 94:e6:f7:06:76:97  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3674  bytes 1519570 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3531  bytes 605307 (605.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

max@max-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ZYXEL-133"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 04:BF:6D:55:0F:0E   
          Bit Rate=86.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:458   Missed beacon:0

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

The command "ip route show" does not yield anything. Also, I tried connecting to the router directly via Ethernet, resulting in the same problem.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You're not getting an ipv4 IP address. Power cycle your router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling IPv6 did not solve the problem, but it has put me on the right track, thanks!

The solution was to manually assign a static IPv4 address, apparently my router's DHCP doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the ipv6 address. Go to network settings and uncheck the "IPv6".

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Google is probably reachable with IP v6. You do not seem to have an ipv4 assigned.

Comment: This apparently does not solve the problem. For some reason I am able to access the URL you posted after disabling IPv6, but other websites still do not respond. Ping does not work after disabling IPv6.